# How to use SQL Server 2012 database in client without Install it complete,

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to use a SQL Server 2012 database in my WPF application, but users can not Install SQL Server 2012 on their computer, and are unhappy about it.

Can someone advise me on this?

Can it silent mode be installed so that it does not require any user intervention?

With respect

Comment: Install it on just a single **server** in that company and let everyone connect to it ...

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the needs of the software.  If data is shared and used with multiple users then install It on a server connect to It.

If the software on my needs interactions from one user use a embedded database like SqlLite.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you M.JackSon , this application is Desktop And not Use in network, and For install on local computer , for sale to Customer.

Comment: Google SqlLite and it should help you out. The syntax is exactly the same as SQL Server 2012.